# How should I order letters in order of frequency?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm to rearrange the letters in a string in order of frequency and then alphabetical order. For instance, "apple" becomes "aelpp". "banana" becomes "bnnaaa".

I know a variety of languages, but I am using Python for now to code it. This is what I have so far, but it does not work because there is no frequency sorting.

```
def order(word):
  word = word.lower()
  storage = [0] * 26
  for c in word:
    storage[ord(c) - 97] += 1
  newWord = []
  for l, c in enumerate(storage):
    for i in range(0, storage[l]):
      newWord.append(chr(l + 97))
  return ''.join(newWord)
```

Any advice on how to most efficiently implement this algorithm correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a (mostly) pythonic example of how to deal with this problem in python,
I hope the comments are sufficient to explain what is happening:

```
words = ["apples", "banannas", "oranges"]

def main():
    # our list of jumbled words
    jumbled = []
    for word in words:
        # dictionary of letter / frequency pairs.
        letters = {};
        # get letter frequency
        for letter in word:
            if letter in letters:
                letters[letter] += 1
            else:
                letters[letter] = 1
        # sort the letter / frequency pairs on descending frequency
        jumbled_word = sorted(letters.items(), key = lambda x: x[1],
                                                              reverse = True)
        # join the letters back together and add to our jumbled words
        jumbled.append(''.join([x[0] for x in jumbled_word]))
        letters = {}

    # print out the jumbled words in alphabetical order
    for x in sorted(jumbled):
        print x

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

this implementation will keep capital letters capital.

Answer (score 1):

For frequency a common tool to use is a hashtable (dictionary in python). I'm not terribly confident with python so I'll give you some psuedo code

```
hashtable table
for character in string
  table[character] +=1;
list partiallySorted = alphabetize(table.keys()) 
list sortedList = stablesort partiallySorted by (table[a]<table[b] iff a<b)
```

The stable sort will maintain relative order among equal elements thus preserving your order.

Luckily for you, since python 2.2 all sorts are guaranteed stable so you can call the library's sort function to do the stable sorting if you don't wish to implement it yourself.